# not executing second condition in for loop

Tags: java, android

I am strange with something in for loop. If i call setCurrentId(1) then generateid will return 0(return statement execute inside for loop ). Again if i call with setCurrentId(2) it returns 0(return statement execute outside for loop ) which is not supposed to.

I have a profile ArrayList which has been created before with id 1,2,3,4. So i am now checking a random id with these id.But in the for loop it only execute 1st time.

```
public void setCurrentId(int id) {

    Log.d("status scd :", "scI a " + id);
    this.current_id = GenerateId(id);
    Log.d("status scd :", "scI b " + this.current_id);

}

public int GenerateId(int profile_id) {
    if (AppController.getInstance().getProfile() != null) {
        Log.d("status scd :", "GI  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < AppController.getInstance().getProfile().size() && AppController.getInstance().getProfile().get(i).getId() == profile_id; i++) {

            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Log result is :

```
status scd :: scI a 1
status scd :: GI  
status scd :: scI b 0
status scd :: scI a 2
status scd :: GI  
status scd :: scI b 0
```

so,i debug and found that 2nd condition is not executing after 1st call of setCurrentId().

When i place the 2nd condition inside if then it works fine. But don't know why this is happening.So, i am curious to figure it out.

here is corrected code :

```
   public void setCurrentId(int id) {
    Log.d("status scd :", "scI a " + id);
    this.current_id = GenerateId(id);
    Log.d("status scd :", "scI b " + this.current_id);
}

public int GenerateId(int profile_id) {
    if (AppController.getInstance().getProfile() != null) {
        Log.d("status scd :", "GI  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < AppController.getInstance().getProfile().size(); i++) {
            if (AppController.getInstance().getProfile().get(i).getId() == profile_id) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the log result :

```
status scd :: scI a 1
status scd :: GI  
status scd :: scI b 0
status scd :: scI a 2
status scd :: GI  
status scd :: scI b 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition in the For loop says AND (&&). The first loop looks for the condition to be true to iterate and since that being false it omits the loop.

Iteration is possible only with True functionality for any multiple conditions in for loop. In your second code snippet loop condition is true until i< the size of Profile List and hence loop being triggered.

@skyman statement **Condition in for loop means 'do when true' so loop body is skipped.** this is correct.

It is good practice to see the second code snippet in real time. Reason being is exception handling. Also, i see in your code snippet conventions are not being used just for your reference.[Java Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

`AppController.getInstance().getProfile().get(i).getId() == profile_id` is probably false for first profile item so you do not step into loop and 0 is returned.

Condition in for loop means 'do when true' so loop body is skipped.

Comment: No. First profile item returned  successfully from inside for loop where i is 0.i have checked it using log.

Comment: True. But check it for `profile_id = 2`. for (i = 0; i < size [it's true] && profile.get(0) [1 != 2 breaks the loop])

Comment: I also checked it. when i=1 then profile_id == 2 . so, it supposed to execute but it executes when i use if statement.